# How to Create a shortcode to this php function

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

This function allows me to show Demo Url on the single product page before cart button. But i want to display it somewhere else using a shortcode. Please help me How to do that-

Here is the code:

```
/**
* Show a Live Demo button on a single product page
*/
function isa_before_add_to_cart_form() {
    global $product;
    $url = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_isa_wc_product_demo_url', true );
    if ( $url ) {
        echo '<p><a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" id="livedemo" class="button primary is-shade box-shadow-3 box-shadow-5-hover" target="_blank" rel="noopener">' .
        __( 'Live Demo', 'textdomain') .
        '</a><p>';
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form','isa_before_add_to_cart_form');
 
/**
 * Display the Demo URL field in the Product Data metabox
 */
function isa_wc_product_add_demo_url_field() {
    echo '<div class="options_group">';
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'          => '_isa_wc_product_demo_url',
            'label'       => __( 'Demo URL', 'textdomain' ), 
            'placeholder' => '',
            'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => __( 'Set a URL that will be displayed on the product page to link to a demo of this product. Full URL starting with "https://"', 'textdomain' )
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'isa_wc_product_add_demo_url_field' );
 
/**
 * Save the Demo URL field value when the produc is saved
 */
function isa_wc_product_save_demo_url_value( $post_id ) {
    $val = trim( get_post_meta( $post_id, '_isa_wc_product_demo_url', true ) );
    $new = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_isa_wc_product_demo_url'] );
    if ( $val != $new ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_isa_wc_product_demo_url', $new );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'isa_wc_product_save_demo_url_value' );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the [add_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) function to do that. You just need to pass your `isa_before_add_to_cart_form` function as a shortcode like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'isa_show_link', 'isa_before_add_to_cart_form );
```

Now you can use the shortcode `[isa_show_link]` to display it anywhere. It's simple.